# Ansible - Convert string to dictionary in Ansible

Tags: python, string, dictionary, ansible

There is a thing bothering me regarding the creation of a dynamic dictionary in ansible.
I have tried the following:

```
- name: Test
      set_fact:
        "available_boards":
            - "{ '{{ 'X' if i % 2 == 0 else 'Y' }}' : {{ hostvars[item].ansible_host }}}"

      loop: "{{groups['boards']}}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: i
```

Assuming the `{{groups['boards']` are 4 then the result is:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "available_boards": [
        "{ 'X' : 10.10.112.90 }",
        "{ 'Y' : 10.10.112.91 }",
        "{ 'X' : 10.10.112.92 }",
        "{ 'Y' : 10.10.112.93 }"
    ]
}
```

However as you can see this results in a list of strings...
The truth is i want dictionaries to manipulate them easier.

I tried everything with single/double quote combination without making it work.
I don't understand why this does not produce a dictionary:

```
- name: Test
      set_fact:
        "available_boards":
            - { "{{ 'X' if i % 2 == 0 else 'Y' }}" : "{{ hostvars[item].ansible_host }}" }
```

But this does not evaluate the key in the condition and produces the literal:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "available_boards": [
        {
            "{{  'X' if i % 2 == 0 else 'Y' }}": "00:15:e3:55:22:67",
            
        },
```

instead of

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "available_boards": [
        {
            'X': "00:15:e3:55:22:67",
            
        },
```

Is it possible to make this substation in jinja work or not? I've been struggling all night.

On the other hand, i was investigating if there was a filter to convert the sting literal to dictionary.
So, if you have the list:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "available_boards": [
        "{ 'X' : 10.10.112.90 }",
        "{ 'Y' : 10.10.112.91 }",
        "{ 'X' : 10.10.112.92 }",
        "{ 'Y' : 10.10.112.93 }"
    ]
}
```

to convert it to this:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "available_boards": [
        { 'X' : 10.10.112.90 },
        { 'Y' : 10.10.112.91 },
        { 'X' : 10.10.112.92 },
        { 'Y' : 10.10.112.93 }
    ]
}
```

So all the string elements of the list would be converted to dictionaries.Should be easy this task? Again all of the available filters in jinja do not do the trick...

thanks for your answers a priori :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to compose a structured data type such as JSON or YAML using string templates is the road to ruin

```yaml
- set_fact:
    available_boards: >-
      {%- set results = [] -%}
      {%- for h in groups['boards'] -%}
      {%-   set _ = results.append({
         'X' if loop.index % 2 == 0 else 'Y': hostvars[h].ansible_host
      }) -%}
      {%- endfor -%}
      {{ results }}
```

Comment: if you check closely , each dict is separate.so.it can have same key.its not the same dictionary that I update...

Comment: Yeah , I did that already mdaniel. Many thanks for the idea!!